# Recaptcha google with EWZRecaptchaBundle for Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, recaptcha

I want to have a recaptcha system to my contact form symfony. For that I use a EWZRecaptchaBundle. But I try lot of stuff tricks for running recaptcha but my form submit run without testing validation recaptcha widget (invisible and visible)

Can you help me to run recaptcha correctly. My submit form run without deal with recaptcha but I have the widget display correctly.

**config.yml**

```
ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    private_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%
    locale_from_request: false
    enabled: true
    verify_host: true
    ajax: false
```

**ContactType**

```
        ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'theme' => 'light',
                    'type'  => 'image',
                    'size'  => 'invisible',
                    'defer' => true,
                    'async' => true,
                    'callback' => 'onReCaptchaSuccess',
                    'bind' => 'contact_submit',
                )
            ),
            'mapped'      => false,
            'constraints' => array(
                new RecaptchaTrue()
            )
            )
        )

//        ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class)

        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'form.submit.send',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn1 form_recaptcha_submit', 'id' => 'contact_submit']
        ])
```

**Twig template**

```
 {{ form_widget(form.recaptcha, { 'attr': {
       'options' : {
            'theme': 'light',
            'type': 'image',
            'size': 'invisible'
        },
  } }) }}
```

**contact (entity)**

I have my field recaptcha

```
private $recaptcha;
```

- I have the widget recaptcha google which display correctly but my submit form don't work with this. never.
- I have registered my domain on google website recaptcha

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the validation in your form (it is also possible to validate in the entity class). Also in my case I did not create a field in my eneity. I prefered to use what we call a "non mapped" field. To use a non mapped field you just need to use 'mapped' => false, in your contactType

I show you below the code I used:

My ContactType:

```
            ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'theme' => 'light',
                        'type' => 'image',
                        'size' => 'normal',
                        'defer' => true,
                        'async' => true,
                    )
                )
                ,
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new RecaptchaTrue()
                )
            ))
```

I give you my config.yml so you can see I don't need that much options to be defined to make recaptcha works:

```
ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key:  xxxx
    private_key: xxxx
    # Not needed as "%kernel.default_locale%" is the default value for the locale key
    locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%
    locale_from_request: true
```

edit: to display the recaptcha widget with twig in my template, I just use {{ form_end(form) }} and the recaptcha widget is on top of the submit button.

edit 2: You don't need to do any validation in your controller but this one:

```
if ($contactForm->isSubmitted() && $contactForm->isValid())
{
   //your logic
}
```

Comment: very similar code I already have. The submit button behaviour as same as before. It don't work with recaptcha system. Widget display but nothing data send to form or others.

Comment: so in your controlleur if you do 
if ($contactForm->isSubmitted() && $contactForm->isValid())
{
   die('hello');
}

you don't see the string "hello" ? If yes then the recapatcha is confirmed.

Comment: How testing robot behaviour for confirm recaptcha run correctly ?

Comment: EwZ Recaptcha bundle handle this process for you.

Comment: No. If I change widget recaptcha 'invisible' to 'normal' and I don't check 'I am not a robot' my form submit all the same. Process recaptcha display ok but not run.

Comment: Which version of Symfony do you use ? Have you a non-mapped filed as I have in my ContactType ? I don't have a field called recaptcha in my database.

Comment: Symfony : 3.2.7 and PHP : 5.6.31. I tested with field and without field in my Contact entity and no mapped options in ContactType. The issue is more complex

Comment: In your config.yml have you enabled the translator ?

translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }

and also set the default locale:

default_locale: '%locale%'

Also if you try with non mapped field. Don't forget to remove the recapatcha field in your db. and to add this line in your contactType 'mapped' => false,